# How to avoid to be redirected by rel=canonical tag while crawling with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, canonical-link

I'm trying to scraping some information from Yelp.com. I'm using Scrapy, and I want to extract some informations from this URL:

```
http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=italiani+&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY%2C+USA&ns=1#find_desc=italian+restaurants&start=0
```

(Searching  italian restaurants in New York).

But I discovered that in HTML code of this page there's the following line:

```
<link href="http://www.yelp.com/search?     find_desc=italiani&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY" rel="canonical">
```

So, while crawling, I recive the results of the canonical page, that actually don't correspond to the page that I specified.
How can I avoid this `rel="canonical"` with Scrapy?

Here the code (I used the tutorial project of Scrapy):

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["yelp.org"]
    start_urls = [
        #"http://www.yelp.com/search?           find_desc=italiani+&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY%2C+USA&ns=1#find_desc=italian+restau       rants&start=0"
    "http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=italiani+&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY%2C+USA&ns=1#find_desc=italian+restaurants&start=10"
]

def parse(self, response):
    filename = "response_body"
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)

    for sel in response.xpath('//div/h3/span'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: what have you done so far ? please post your code?